# Django displaying CPU average for many VMs using ListView

Tags: django-views

I have a model that stores a list of VMs and their management IPs.  I have another model that stores cpu consumption for all of the VMs tied to the foreign key of the VM.  There is a cron job that will run every five minutes to populate the Cpu model with the cpu consumption of each VM.

What I want to do is create a table in a template that lists all VMs, with an average of the CPU consumption, and max CPU consumption.

```
'''

#models.py
from django.db import models

class VMs (models.Model):
    mgmtIP = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    hostName = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hostName

class Cpu (models.Model):
    hostName = models.ForeignKey(F5Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cpuAverage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
    whenReported = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)



#views.py
from .models import Cpu, VMs

class Report(ListView):
    model = VMs
    template_name = 'report.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Cpu.objects.filter(hostName= self.hostName).aggregate(Avg(cpuAverage))
        return queryset
'''
```

I can get the basic ListView to show the VMs in my template but when I try to add the queryset it stops displaying anything.

!!!Update!!!
I am able to get it to sort of work with this

```
'''
class Report(ListView):
    model = VMs
    context_object_name = 'cpu_list'
    template_name = 'report.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Report, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({             'cpuAverageReport':Cpu.objects.filter(hostName_id='1').aggregate(Avg('cpuAverage')),
            }) 
        return context
'''
```

The problem is I need the hostName id to be dynamic.  It should be which ever host it is currently looping through.  I put in '1' just to test the rest of my syntax...  I've tried 'self.kwargs['id'], self.args['id'], just id, VMs.id, and probably a thousand other combinations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is aggregate only returns one line.  I needed to change it for annotate.

```
'''
cpuAverageReport':Cpu.objects.values('hostName_id').annotate(Avg('cpuAverage'))
'''
```

Then I needed to add a for loop into my for loop and an if to match the records up with each other in my template. like so...

```
'''
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td><td>CPU Average</td>
        </tr>
            {% for x in report %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ x.hostName }}</td>                
                {% for y in cpuAverageReport %}
                    {% if x.id == y.hostName_id %}
                        <td>{{ y.cpuAverage__avg }}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>
'''
```